# acro vs. acronym - capitalization and reintroduction of acronyms

Tags: acronyms, acro

I browsed the internet for quite some time, but have not found a solution to the following problem pertaining to the use of acronyms.

1. I want to use capitalization of acronyms as provided by the `acro` package, e.g. `\Ac{bla}`.
2. I want that acronyms are "reintroduced" in, say, every section or chapter, as provided by the `acronym` package.

Is there any possibility to get this "combined" functionality, for example by adapting either the `acro` or the `acronym` package?

Many thanks for your help in advance!

Cheers, from a desperate university dude.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `etoolbox`' `\preto` to add `acro`'s `\acresetall` to every call of `\chapter` or `\section`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{foo}{
  short = foo ,
  long  = the description of foo
}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\section{\acresetall}

\begin{document}

\section{One}
\Ac{foo}, now short: \ac{foo}.

\section{two}
\Ac{foo}, now short: \ac{foo}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain the desired result with the package `glossaries`.
1) `\Ac{}` is in the package
2) Is obtained by redifining the section command to include `\glsresetall` to reset if the acronym has been used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym,shortcuts]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{tedc}{TEDC}{tunable electrical dispersion compensation}
\let\oldsection\thesection
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\oldsection\glsresetall}
\begin{document}
\section{intro}
\Ac{tedc}

\ac{tedc}

\ac{tedc}
\section{new topic}
\ac{tedc}

\ac{tedc}
\end{document}
```